# Parsing Different Json Objects in WP8

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

Please help me in parsing this Json sample as I'm not able to parse it because of the complexity of it as well as different objects inside it. I'm able to parse Json when a list of same objects & same structure but not like the one below.

```
   [
      {

       "notificationBrowserHead":
       {

           "notificationId": 4,
           "notificationType": "NEW_PRODUCT",
           "creationTime": 1421933381000,
           "notificationNormalUserId": 4,
           "notificationViewed": false
       },
       "brandIdAndNameHolder":
       {
           "brandId": 1,
           "name": "B1"
       },
       "brandLogo": null,
       "productIdAndNameHolder":
       {
           "productId": 1,
           "name": "JK product1"
       }
   },
   {
       "notificationBrowserHead":
       {
           "notificationId": 2,
           "notificationType": "USER_INT_COMMENT",
           "creationTime": 1421924403000,
           "notificationNormalUserId": 2,
           "notificationViewed": false
       },
       "uploadId": 22,
       "uploadThumbnail": "/mediaUrl/location/thumbNail",
       "uploadDescription": "upload 1 location desc",
       "notificationCreator":
       {
           "normalUserId": 90,
           "displayName": "amit"
       },
       "uploadRemoved": false
   },
   {
       "notificationBrowserHead":
       {
           "notificationId": 1,
           "notificationType": "NEW_LOCATION_VOTE",
           "creationTime": 1421924403000,
           "notificationNormalUserId": 1,
           "notificationViewed": false
       },
       "locationIdAndNameHolder":
       {
           "locationId": 11,
           "name": "Current King JK"
       },
       "locationLogo": null
   }
]
```

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: Paste your JSon in the website http://json2csharp.com/ This will give you an object model to work with.

Comment: Yes it did gave me all the classes but because I need to call the second part of the Json at runtime with condition specified by "notificationType". How do I do it???

Comment: questions like these are the worst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you receive different set of json properties when your NotificationType varies.

Solution 1:

Define all your members(the collection of all your properties that you receive for different types of notification) in  a Class and use it for DeSerialization, so that the unwanted properties for your particular notification type will be null.

Solution 2:

Parser manually. [Newtonsoft json documentation here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Make class "Notifications (or something)" and put inside everything you got back from json2csharp.com site, then use this framework http://www.newtonsoft.com/json to deserialize data as you download it from server and you should be able to get notificationType by Object.Notificationbrowserhead[x].notificationType or similar.